# Servlet filtering not applying on JSF navigation rule

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, servlet-filters

We have servlet filter which verifies couple of session variables before JSF view display. Some how when a navigation rule is invoked in bean using handleNavigation(...) method, filter is not being called. Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>JSF</display-name>
    <description>
        JSF
    </description>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>myFilterClassPath</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pathtoAppServletClass</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And navigation rule is faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>nextPage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/nextPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

And here is code bean invoking:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "nextPage");
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have break points and System.outs inside Filter. Right now this filter does nothing than System.out the session variables I am looking for and call chain.doFilter(..). JSF 2.1 and Jboss7.1

Comment: @BalusC: Another observation is, on first call, filter being invoked, while navigation rule forwards control to nextPage, then server filter is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you expect the filter to be called for `nextPage.xhtml` as well? JSF navigation doesn't perform a request, forward or include. It just creates a new view within the very same request which is then to be rendered.

If you need to create a brand new request, call [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/nextPage.xhtml");
```

Or if you're actually inside an action method, return the navigation outcome with `?faces-redirect=true`:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "/nextPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Or as an alternative, depending on the concrete functional requirement, use a [`ViewHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html) instead of a `Filter` so that you can hook on [`createView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#createView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hi BalusC, I am already in action method, may be ?faces-redirect=true work (I don't think ViewHandler is best for my requirement). I am off for the day. Will test as soon as I login tomorrow. Ir-relevant question, Is there anyway we can map filter to be invoked all operations (new View creation also)?

Comment: Isn't it slight deviation from jsp/servlet filtering? In JSP/Servlet filtering applies to all calls right?

Comment: Filters are high level and are for JSF only useful if you want to intercept on incoming requests. If you want to intercept on JSF internal navigation as well, then a `ViewHandler` is probably a better idea. But what exactly is that filter supposed to do? Authentication? Why would you navigate to an unauthenticated view in first place?

Comment: Hi BalusC, Filters in my case are really for redirecting page. Authentication took care by some other module. Guys who designed this for JSF1.2 and JSP seems complicated simple functional requirement. Let me try to put an abstract here. There is nextPage with couple of text boxes and button, on this button click, we are invoking action in a bean. There we are checking for certain session variables. If ONE OF those session variables are not present, again nextPage view need to render with tool-tip message (for button) saying particular session variable doesn't exist.

Comment: May be you can think link this too, you are in login page, when click on login, if some of the variables are not in session variable, again login page need to be rendered with tool tip message on login button. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, the enduser ends up in the very same page anyway? Why not just doing the check in the `rendered` attribute instead?